# PUT or PATCH for hateoas relation update

Tags: spring, http, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I would like understand the best practice for update foreign key with spring hateoas requests.

Is it best to use:

```
Url: "http://host/entity1/{{entity1_id}}/entity2" 
Method: PUT    
Body: "http://host/entity2/{{entity2_id}}"
ContentType: "text/uri-list"
```

Or:

```
Url: "http://host/entity1/{{entity1_id}}"
Method: PATCH
Body: {"entity2": "http://host/entity2/{{entity2_id}}"}
ContentType: "application/json"
```

Thank you all!

Comment: PUT if you want to **replace** the entire entity with the given data, PATCH if you want to **update** only the specified fields of the given entity.

Comment: Read examples, i'm not asking difference between put and patch with same api. These are two different approaches and i would like understand if there is a best practice and why use one side over the other! Thank you anyway for your comment!

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the actual payload of the resource to be manipulated.

In any case, PATCH with application/json is incorrect, as application/json does not habe defined semantics for PATCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PUT** is for *idempotent change of the whole resource*, so you have to put all the resource data. Top replace a resource you have to completely specify its characteristics.

**PATCH** allows *partial resource changes*, by incomplete data.

If your entity2 has more data, besides a link another entity, then PACTH is more applicable to change the foreign key only.

See in [HTTP Methods sepcification](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml).